# Pegar StartAddress com o nome do Modulo de uma Thread de um programa externo

Tags: c#, thread

Estou tentando diferenciar as threads de um determinado programa. com o software "ProcessExplorer" eu consigo facilmente pelo Start Address, já que aparece o nome do método:

[image: start address print]

Tentei pegar o StartAddress com o esse código em c#:

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (ProcessThread CurrentThread in process[0].Threads)
{
     Console.WriteLine(CurrentThread.StartAddress);
}
```

e este foi o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O StartAddress veio tudo com o mesmo valor, então tentei utilizar este código:

```
                    IntPtr pOpenThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)CurrentThread.Id);

                    if (pOpenThread != IntPtr.Zero)
                     {
                          var buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);

                          int result = -1;
                          try
                          {
                              result = NtQueryInformationThread(pOpenThread, ThreadInfoClass.ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress, buf, IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero);
                          }
                          finally
                          {
                              IntPtr CurrentThread = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(buf);
                              Console.WriteLine("TID: " + CurrentThread.Id + " StartAddress " + FinalResult);
                          }
                     }
```

e teste foi o resultado:

[image: result]
Resolveu meu problema por um tempo mas depois os StartAddress mudavam... preciso pegar o nome do modulo para conseguir identificar cada Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é exatamente a informação que aparece no ProcessExplorer, mas o processo tem os módulos, a thread não.

Para pegar os nomes dos módulos como pede na pergunta, pode fazer assim:

```
ProcessModuleCollection currentThreads = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")[0].Modules;

foreach (ProcessModule modulo in currentThreads)
{
    Console.WriteLine(modulo.ModuleName);
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Preciso diferenciar as threads, isso infelizmente nao ajuda.